# Integrating 2-form

Tags: integration, manifolds, differential-forms

> > In $\mathbb{R}^3$ I consider the compact 2-dimensional manifold
> >     $$
> > M=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2: z=xy\right\}
> > $$
> >     which is orientated by the (global) map $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3, (x,y)\mapsto (x,y,xy)$.
> >     Furthermore a 2-form is given by
> >     $$
> > \omega:=3zdy\wedge dz+(x^2+y^2)dz\wedge dx+xzdx\wedge dy.
> > $$
> >     Consider
> >     $$
> > A:=\left\{(x,y,z)\in M: \lvert x\rvert\leq 1,\lvert y\rvert\leq 1\right\}
> > $$
> >     and my task now is to calculate the integral
> >     $$
> > \int_{A}\omega.
> > $$

First of all i calculated the pullback $\phi^{\star}\omega$, which is to my calculation
$$
\phi^{\star}\omega=x^2ydx\wedge dy-(x^2+y^2)dx\wedge y dx+xdy+3xydy\wedge ydx+xdy\\
=x^2ydx\wedge dy-(x^2+y^2)xdx\wedge dy-2xy^2dx\wedge dy\\
=(-x^3+x^2y-4xy^2)dx\wedge dy
$$

To my opinion it is $\phi^{-1}(A)=[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$.

So if my calculations are correct I have to calculate the following integral:
$$
\int\limits_{[-1,1]\times [-1,1]}(-x^3+x^2y-4xy^2)dx\wedge dy
$$

1.) Is this right?
2.) If yes, how can I calculate this?

Greetings!

Comment: I think you should put $\Big(\phi'(s,t)e_1,\phi'(s,t)e_2\Big)$ after the 2-form, do the calculations, then integrate in $s,t\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Hm, sorry, I do not understand what you mean. May you explain it?

Comment: a 2-form must be computed in two vectors, when you use a parameterization such as $\phi$, your 2-form will be computed in $\Big(\phi'(s,t)e_1,\phi'(s,t)e_2\Big)$, where $\phi'(s,t)$ is the jacobian matrix.

Comment: I forgot an extra detail, when you use this parameterization $\phi$, you should substitute $x$ for $\phi_1(s,t)$, same for $y$ and $z$. Its is performed as a change of variables. In short, if $M$ is parameterized by $\phi:B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$, where $B$ is some closed rectangule, and $\omega$ is some k-form, then $\int_M \omega=\int_B \omega(\phi)(\phi'e_1,\ldots,\phi'e_k)$

Comment: I do not understand a word of what you are trying to tell me, I am really sorry... Do you mean that I can write the pullback as $\phi^{\star}\omega=gdx\wedge dy$ with $g=\sum\limits_{i_1<i_2}(f_{i_1 i_2}\circ\phi)\mbox{det}\frac{\partial(\phi_{i_1},...,\phi_{i_2})}{\partial(x,y)}$?

Comment: Hm, maybe I am too stupid by I still do not know how to calculate the integral above. ;(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, your computation of $\phi^\ast \omega$ is correct, and you were on the right track. If you want to be completely pedantic, you have the following ingredients:

1. your given map $\phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to M$,
2. the inclusion $\iota : M \to \mathbb{R}^3$,
3. the $2$-form $\omega = 3z dy \wedge dz + (x^2+y^2)dz \wedge dx + xz dx \wedge dy$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$,
4. the closed subset $A = \phi([-1,1]^2)$,

and you want to compute
$$
 \int_A \iota^\ast\omega = \int_{[-1,1]^2} (\iota \circ \phi)^\ast\omega = \int_{[-1,1]^2} \psi^\ast \omega,
$$
where, for convenience,
$$
 (\psi^1(x,y),\psi^2(x,y),\psi^3(x,y)) = \psi(x,y) := (\iota \circ \phi)(x,y) = (x,y,xy).
$$

First, observe that
$$
 \psi^\ast dx = d \psi^1 = \frac{\partial \psi^1}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial \psi^1}{\partial y} dy = dx,\\
 \psi^\ast dy = d \psi^2 = \frac{\partial \psi^2}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial \psi^2}{\partial y} dy = dy,\\
 \psi^\ast dz = d \psi^3 = \frac{\partial \psi^3}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial \psi^3}{\partial y} dy = ydx + xdy.
$$
Hence,
$$
 \psi^\ast \omega = \psi^\ast(3z dy \wedge dz + (x^2+y^2)dz \wedge dx + xz dx \wedge dy)\\
 = 3\psi^3 \psi^\ast dy \wedge \psi^\ast dz + ((\psi^1)^2+(\psi^2)^2)\psi^\ast dz \wedge \psi^\ast dx + \psi^1 \psi^2 \psi^\ast dx \wedge \psi^\ast dy\\
 = 3xy dy \wedge (ydx+xdy) + (x^2+y^2)(ydx+xdy)\wedge dx + x(xy)dx\wedge dy\\
 = -3xy^2 dx \wedge dy -x(x^2+y^2)dx \wedge dy + x^2 y dx \wedge dy\\
 = (-x^3+x^2y-4xy^2)dx \wedge dy,
$$
exactly as you computed.

Finally, since $dx \wedge dy$ is just the volume form on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it follows that, *by definition*,
$$
 \int_A \iota^\ast \omega = \int_{[-1,1]^2} \psi^\ast \omega = \int_{[-1,1]^2} (-x^3+x^2y-4xy^2)dx \wedge dy := \int_{[-1,1]^2} (-x^3+x^2y-4xy^2)dx dy,
$$
which is just an honest-to-goodness double integral over a rectangle in the plane.

Comment: Thanks! The only unclear point for me is to see what $dx\wedge dy$ is and how I can calculate this.

Comment: @WishingFish this is a great example of how to actually compute pull-backs in a concrete setting. Nice work.

Comment: Puh, I do not understand the last step from $dx\wedge dy$ to $dxdy$...

Comment: @math12 that is the definition of integrating a two-form on a subset of the plane. The expression with $dx \wedge dy$ is an integral of a two-form, the expression with $dx dy$ is an area integral which is properly calculated by iterating integrals $\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1} (...)dx \, dy$. How do you define integration of a form? At some point it has to get back to ordinary multivariate integration on euclidean space. This is that point.

Comment: I define integration of form over a compact set as the integral of the pullback  - just as  I calculated here..

Comment: An $n$-form $\omega$ on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is necessarily of the form
$$
 \omega = f dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n,
$$
where $f \in C^\infty(U)$ and $dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$ is the volume form on $U$, and the integral of $\omega$ over an $n$-dimensional submanifold $K$ of $U$ is *defined* as the integral of the scalar function $f$ over the subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e.,
$$
 \int_K \omega = \int_K f dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n := \int_K f dx^1 \cdots dx^n.
$$

Comment: Thank you, and excuse my confusion!! I looked it up in my book and found this definition. I forgot it, now I remember on this definition. Now I calculate the integral and then it is finished. Thanbk you so much for your great help!

Comment: The integral is 0.