# What exactly does "outward normal vector" means when talking about an orientation?

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms, surface-integrals

I am asked to calculate the integral of a $2$-form on the sphere:
$$ \int_{S^2} \frac{x\mathrm{d}y\wedge \mathrm{d}z-y\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}z+z\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

where we choose the orientation of $S^2$ with "outward normal vector".

So what does this exactly mean by saying "outward normal vector"? For example, to start with my calculation, I need to find an atlas compatible with the given orientation. How should I justify whether the atlas given by Riemann stereographic projection is compatible with the desired orientation or not?

By the way, how about saying that choosing an anticlockwise orientation of $S^1$?

Any Hints or Solutions for this integral are welcomed. THANKS!

Comment: I do not understand your "by the way ..."  Can you clarify that?

Comment: Let $\omega:=x\mathrm{d}y\wedge \mathrm{d}z-y\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}z+z\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y$.
$d\omega= 3dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ wherein associativity and anti-commutativity of the wedge product have been used.
So the integral becomes $\int_{S^2} w$ which is $\int_{D^2}dw$ by the Stokes' theorem. And the latter is just $3-$ times the volume of the $2-$ disk $D^2$, i.e., $4\pi$.

Comment: @Koro  The main point, as far as I could tell, was orientation issues. You shoveled those under the rug. Also, I suspect that the OP hasn't yet gotten to Stokes's Theorem.

Comment: @Koro Do you mean $3$-disk?

Comment: @Zoudelong: I meant the disk $\{x\in \mathbb R^3:\|x\|\le 1\}$. I am used to denote the unit disk by $\mathbb D$ so I said $D^2$ earlier.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Kurt that you should be looking at polar/spherical coordinates and not stereographic projection. This is true in general, but particularly because of the form of your integrand. But I'm going to answer your question because it should help you build some geometric intuition for what's going on here.

You can do a formal computation, but I recommend pictures here. The answer will be that stereographic projection from the north pole is orientation-reversing if we use the standard orientation on the $xy$-plane and stereographic projection from the south pole is orientation-preserving.

Do stereographic projection from the *north* pole to the $xy$-plane. Think in polar coordinates on the plane: Moving radially outward moves you up a great circle on the sphere; moving counterclockwise around a circle centered at the origin moves you counterclockwise around a latitude circle on the sphere. The cross product of the respective tangent vectors to those curves points *inward*. Thus, in order to get an outward-pointing normal, we must reverse the order of our two coordinates. Using $(\theta,r)$ as polar coordinates on the plane will give an orientation-preserving parametrization of the sphere when we stereographically project. You can certainly write this all out formally and compute partial derivatives.

In order to address (what I think is) your question about the orientation on $S^1$, here's the general set-up. In general, given a hypersurface in $\Bbb R^{k+1}$, we orient the tangent plane at a point as follows: We say that $(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ is a positively-oriented basis if and only if the ordered basis $(\vec n,v_1,\dots,v_k)$ is a positively-ordered basis for $\Bbb R^{k+1}$. In the case $k=1$, this means that $(\vec n,v_1)$ should be a right-handed basis; in the case $k=2$, this means that $v_1\times v_2$ should point in the direction of (positive) $\vec n$. Rephrasing the latter, if you stand upright along $\vec n$ and look down to the tangent plane, $v_1,v_2$ must be a right-handed basis.

Comment: THANKS a lot for your long post!  I need some time to compare your answer with what I've learned.

Comment: Of course. Feel free to ask follow-up questions. Also, you may find some of my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile) on this material helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For the sphere we use polar coordinates:
$$\tag{1}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\varphi\,\sin\theta\\\sin\varphi\,\sin\theta\\\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
dx&=-\sin\varphi\,\sin\theta\,d\varphi+\cos\varphi\,\cos\theta\,d\theta\,,\\[2mm]
dy&=\cos\varphi\,\sin\theta\,d\varphi+\sin\varphi\,\cos\theta\,d\theta\,,\\[2mm]
dz&=-\sin\theta\,d\theta\,,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
dy\wedge dz&=\cos\varphi\,\sin^2\theta\;d\theta\wedge d\varphi\,,\\[2mm]
-dx\wedge dz&=\sin\varphi\,\sin^2\theta\;d\theta\wedge d\varphi\,,\\[2mm]
dx\wedge dy&=\sin\theta\,\cos\theta\;d\theta\wedge d\varphi\,.
\end{align}
This system can be written in vector form as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
dy\wedge dz\\-dx\wedge dz\\dx\wedge dy\end{pmatrix}
=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\cos\varphi\,\sin\theta\\\sin\varphi\,\sin\theta\\\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}}_{\textstyle(1)}\sin\theta\;d\theta\wedge d\varphi\,.
$$
Note that the vector (1) points out of the sphere and has length one
so we can identify it as the outward pointing unit normal $\vec n$
to the sphere $S^2\,.$

Recall the definition of positively oriented basis in Ted Shifrin's answer.

In this case: Two orthogonal tangent vectors at the point $p$ on the sphere given by (1) are

\begin{align}
\vec v_1&:=\partial_\theta\begin{pmatrix}\cos\varphi\,\sin\theta\\\sin\varphi\,\sin\theta\\\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}\cos\varphi\,\cos\theta\\\sin\varphi\,\cos\theta\\-\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}\,,\\[2mm]
\vec v_2&:=\partial_\varphi\begin{pmatrix}\cos\varphi\,\sin\theta\\\sin\varphi\,\sin\theta\\\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\sin\varphi\,\sin\theta\\\cos\varphi\,\sin\theta\\0\end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{align}
It is easy to check that
$$
\vec v_1\times\vec v_2=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\varphi\,\sin\theta\\\sin\varphi\,\sin\theta\\\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\sin\theta=\vec n\sin\theta\,.
$$
Therefore $(\vec n,\vec v_1,\vec v_2)$ is a positively oriented basis for $\mathbb R^3$ and $(\vec v_1,\vec v_2)$ a positively oriented basis for
the tangent space of $S^2\,.$

Comment: No, orientation is *not* built into the $2$-form. The orientation is in fact determined by whether $d\theta\wedge d\varphi$ or $d\varphi\wedge d\theta$ is positive (i.e., evaluates to a positive number on a positively-oriented basis for the tangent space). You have to look at the actual parametrization and decide in which order to list the variables.

Comment: @TedShifrin . Thanks again for reading my posts so carefully. I see the point and can adopt that view. In some [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/456600/949989) though one can read that the area form $d\theta\wedge d\varphi$ is integrated as $\iint ...\,d\theta\,d\varphi$ which does not have a sign convention (always positive).

Comment: There's no difference between $\iint \dots d\theta\,d\varphi$ and $\iint\dots d\varphi\,d\theta$. The actual definition of integrating an $n$-form is that *first* one must have an orientation-preserving chart $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and write the form as $f(x)dx_1\wedge\dots\dots dx_n$, in that specific order. I find that post very sloppy: I didn't notice that he addressed orientation at all.

Comment: @TedShifrin May I ask one more question? Is there any sign ambiguity or freedom of choice when $d\theta\wedge d\varphi=d\theta\otimes d\varphi-d\varphi\otimes d\theta$ which evaluates on the ordered basis $(\partial_\theta,\partial_\varphi)$ to $+1$ and on $(\partial_\varphi,\partial_\theta)$ to $-1\,?$

Comment: Kurt, I don't understand your question. I agree that $d\theta\wedge d\varphi$ is the $2$-tensor you wrote. So, by definition, it evaluates to $+1$ on $(\partial_\theta,\partial_\varphi)$ and evaluates to $-1$ on $(\partial_\varphi,\partial_\theta)$.

Comment: That question is triggered by your first comment. In other words: I understood this in the mean time as: $(\partial_\theta,\partial_\varphi)$ is  the positively-oriented basis. We cannot change our mind and say that this shall be negatively-oriented.

Comment: I think there was a typo in your last comment/question, which is why I was confused. The point is that we have to check whether $\partial_\varphi\times\partial_\theta$ points in the correct normal direction (outward) or whether it is $\partial_\theta\times\partial_\varphi$ that does. This determines which chart — $(\varphi,\theta)$ or $(\theta,\varphi)$ — is the correct chart to be using.